# New Windows installation using 34GB of system files

Tags: windows, windows-10, storage

My girlfriend just bought a new laptop, it comes with Windows pre-installed. I went to check the storage and to my surprise it's taking up a whopping **34GB for system files** as well **8GB for Reserved Storage**.

I ran Storage Sense, but that didn't seem to change anything.

What's going on? Can this be fixed with a fresh Windows installation rather than the manufacturer's installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely that the manufacturer included a restore image as well as install "bloatware" aka software supported by the manufacturer where they either use these tools for configuring the hardware or promotional deals with other companies. (they get money to put software on the pc preinstalled, that once you run it, you need to buy a subscription in order to use it.

Because of this, a fresh windows reinstall is always recommended by the more experienced users, to get rid of all the bloatware. You can always download the drivers from their website or a cd, but make sure you have a 2nd pc at handy in case you need to install something like a network card driver and you then also need a usb stick obviously.

So what you do is boot into Windows Setup using a USB install stick you can make using the Media Creation Tool, then at the section where you partition your drives, remove all partitions until it says unpartitioned space. Click that space and hit install. Windows Installer will then make the 4 recommended partitions for you. 3 system/recovery partitions, with a total of <1 GB and the rest of the drive is your main windows partition.

Comment: That's what I thought, haven't used Windows in ages but it did seem weird. I've got the product key so I'll do a full reinstall as soon as possible. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: New pc's often have the device registred either through UEFI or from windows online database. Upon the new install, when it asks for the serial key, just skip it. Chances are big that it will activate automatically. And if not, then you can always enter the productkey. As long as the hardware does not change, this works 9 out of 10 times.

Comment: Do make a list of all drivers in use before though. And do download them ahead of reinstall. Nothing more frustrating than needing to download a network driver and only haveing 1 computer available. (or rather, unavailable).